# Connecting Tranco Google BigQuery with Metabase

Tags: google-bigquery, metabase

I am trying to connect third party ranking management system (https://tranco-list.eu/) with metabase. Tranco is giving us an option to see the record on Google BigQuery but when I am trying to connect the Tranco with Metabase then it is asking for dataset from my Google cloud console project. Since Tranco is an external database source and I don't have access to the dataset Id from this.

If you want to get the result of tranco in Google BigQuery then run below query.

```
select * from `tranco.daily.daily` where domain ='google.com' limit 10
```

When I am searching Tranco in `public dataset` then also I am not finding this over their also. Is anyone aware of, how to add the third party dataset to our Google cloud project.

[image: Metabase view]

[image: Google cloud console to add the Public dataset]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It won't index the tables, etc, but if you connect to any dataset with a service account, I think you should still be able to query the other dataset with the fully qualified query above.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried to connect with my service principle with enough privileges'. It is asking for dataset Id and when I am specifying `tranco` as a dataset then it is not showing no dataset found.

Comment: Connect metabase to a different, owned, dataset, and then use a fully qualified query after connected.

Comment: @HimanshuJain Hello, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can’t read the Tranco dataset directly from BigQuery; but, what you can do is to load the CSV data from Tranco into a Cloud Storage Bucket and then read your bucket in BigQuery.

When you load data from Cloud Storage into a BigQuery table, the dataset that contains the table must be in the same regional or multi- regional location as the Cloud Storage bucket.

Note that it has the next limitations:

- CSV files do not support nested or repeated data.
- Remove byte order mark (BOM) characters. They might cause unexpected
  issues.
- If you use gzip compression, BigQuery cannot read the data in
  parallel. Loading compressed CSV data into BigQuery is slower than
  loading uncompressed data.
- You cannot include both compressed and uncompressed files in the same
  load job.
- The maximum size for a gzip file is 4 GB. When you load CSV or JSON
  data, values in DATE columns must use the dash (-) separator and the
  date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).
- When you load JSON or CSV data, values in TIMESTAMP columns must use
  a dash (-) separator for the date portion of the timestamp, and the
  date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).
  The hh:mm:ss (hour-minute-second) portion of the timestamp must use a
  colon (:) separator.

Also, you can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) if you don’t know how you can upload and read your CSV data.

And also in the [next link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) I'm sending you is a step by step guide in how yo can create / select the bucket you will use.